# I am having trouble understanding the flow when there are multiple fork processes running

Tags: c, process, fork, exec

I am running a program where it runs multiple processes (in this case, commands). I am stuck in running multiple processes, as it repeats and runs pieces of code multiple times. I am having a LOT of trouble trying to follow what is going on.

I've already looked at numerous youtube videos and other SO questions about this.

Below is a variant of my code, including pseudocode:

```
int forking(char **command) {

pid_t parentPID = getpid();
pid_t childPID = fork();

if(childPID < 0) {
    printf("Fork failed\n");
} else if(childPID == 0) { //child process
    printf("Child PID: %d\n", getpid());
} else {
    printf("Parent PID: %d\n",
}

}

int main() {

    //open file of commands, each spaced by a newline

    printf("Main PID: %d\n", parentPID);
    while((getline(&command, &len_buffer, file_pointer)) != -1) {
        printf("-----------------\n);
        //parse command using strtok() to use execvp()
        pid = forking(parsed_command_array);
        if(pid == parentPID) {
            printf("This is the parent: %d\n", pid);
        else {
            printf("This is child, pid is: %d\n", pid);
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to print the following output for 2 commands:

```
------------------------
Main PID: 42729
Parent PID: 42729
This is parent: 42729
------------------------
Main PID: 42729
Child PID: 42730
This is child, pid is: 42730
------------------------
Main PID: 42729
Parent PID: 42729
This is parent: 42729
Child PID: 42731
This is child, pid is: 42731
Parent PID: 42730
This is child, pid is: 42730
Child PID: 42732
This is child, pid is: 42732
```

I wanted the code to, for every command in a while loop, to:
1. Parse the command for execvp (which I've already done)
2. Call fork in a function and return the PID. If the PID is the parent, ignore, if the PID is the child, print the PID.

I also wanted to keep the control in the parent, so that when I run fork, I wanted to grab the child PID, run the process in the child, then go back to parent.

I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong, and I'm getting really confused as to why the parent ran initially, then in the second loop through while, it prints the child process out, then in the third loop, it prints the parent, then the command 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the `while` loop after the first pass you have two processes.  Both of those processes go back to the top of the loop and both fork a new process.  Now you have 4 processes, and on the next iteration they will all fork and now you have 8.

You want the child process to either call `exit` or `execvp` so that it doesn't keep looping.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still having trouble understanding - at the end of the first `while` loop, if there were two processes, why didn't it go back and print the PID of the child inside the `forking()` function? It seemed like it printed the parent's PID, and just kept going to the second loop.

Comment: @B.M.Corwen On the first loop it prints the parent 42729 and the child 42730.  On the next loop it print child 42731 of parent 42729 and child 42732 of parent 42730 (which is the first child).

Comment: Oh okay, that makes a little more sense, but why would `execvp()' prevent it from looping? I am using `waitpid()` with the `WNOHANG` option, will that help?

Comment: @B.M.Corwen When you call `execve` you're starting a new program in the same process.  That function doesn't return if it's successful.